# HBase insert error: No protocol version header

Tags: python, hbase, thrift

I know there are more questions with this issue, but none of them seems to say how to solve this problem.

I'm using happybase python package to connect to HBase thrift server and I'm getting this error when trying to insert data.

I installed happybase 1.1.0 and I'm working against HBase 2.0.0 with Hortonworks Data Platform.

I started my thrift server with the following command:

```
 /usr/hdp/current/hbase-master/bin/hbase-daemon.sh start thrift -p 12345
```

And I'm trying to connect to the server with the following code:

```
import happybase
try:
    connection = happybase.Connection('HBaseMaster', port=12345, ocol='binary')
    table = connection.table('images_tbc')
    table.put("test_key", {"mycf:field": "test_data"})

except Exception as e:
    print('HBase insert error: '+ str(e))
```

Getting the error "no protocol version header" when I try to put the data.

This is the exception stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
 File "/usr/local/airflow/dags/Helpers.py", line 161, 
 in insertImageIntoHBase
     table.put(rowKey, {"raw_data:image_bytes": data})   
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/happybase/table.py", line 464,
 in put
     batch.put(row, data)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/happybase/batch.py", line 137,
 in __exit__
     self.send()
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/happybase/batch.py", line 60,
 in send
     self._table.connection.client.mutateRows(self._table.name, bms, {})
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 198,
 in _req
     return self._recv(_api)
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/thriftpy/thrift.py", line 210,
 in _recv
     fname, mtype, rseqid = self._iprot.read_message_begin()
 File "thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.pyx", line 439, 
 in cybin.TCyBinaryProtocol.read_message_begin
   (thriftpy/protocol/cybin/cybin.c:6470) cybin.ProtocolError: No protocol version header
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I do not know much about happybase, but the error traces back to [this piece of code](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/e44f6a9e06aa0ae42463a791357c0e5c18020c59/lib/py/src/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.py)

From that would deduce that one end has enabled strict read/writes (probably the client), while the other end (the server) does not. What I can't tell is, where this is to be configured in happybase.

Comment: I already read about this piece of code, and I tried to force to set strictRead and write to False in the code in the installed package (I know that is not a good idea and it didn't work for me, maybe the .pyc files where already generated and took the old ones...) I can't find any configuration parameter on happybase to set strict mode to false.

Comment: I see here that setting http mode and proxy user to false could solve the issue. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Web-UI-Hue-Beeswax/Sharing-how-to-solve-HUE-and-HBase-connect-problem-on-CDH-6/td-p/82030 (Maybe it forces not to use the binary protocol). But, according to this tutorial https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/87655/start-and-test-hbase-thrift-server-in-a-kerberised.html, those settings should be set to true if kerberos is used, which is my scenario

Comment: No, it does not work! I was only commenting that I read changing this setting to false could solve the issue (it still does not solve it for me..) Even I cant turn off this setting because it is needed to work with Kerberos it seems